# BeanInstantiationException Error when try to save Artist Entity

Tags: java, spring, jpa

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'artist' defined in file
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.musicreview.model.Artist]: No default constructor found;
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.musicreview.model.Artist.()

```
@Entity
@Repository
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
public class Artist {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "artist_firstname")
    private String artist_firstname;

    @Column(name = "artist_secondname")
    private String artist_secondname;

    @Column(name = "artist_nickname")
    private String artist_nickname;

    @ManyToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "artist_recordlabel", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "artist_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "label_id"))
    private Set<RecordLabel> recordLabels;

    @ManyToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable (name = "artist_musicrelease", joinColumns = @JoinColumn (name = "artist_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn (name = "musicrelease_id"))
    private Set <MusicRelease> musicReleaseSet;


    public Artist(String artist_firstname, String artist_secondname, String artist_nickname) {
        this.artist_firstname = artist_firstname;
        this.artist_secondname = artist_secondname;
        this.artist_nickname = artist_nickname;
    }
}


    -- Table: Artist
CREATE TABLE artist (
  id                INT          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  artist_firstname  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  artist_secondname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  artist_nickname   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB;
-- Table: Artist
CREATE TABLE artist (
  id                INT          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  artist_firstname  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  artist_secondname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  artist_nickname   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB;
-- Table for mapping artist and label: artist_recordlabel
CREATE TABLE artist_musicrelease (
  artist_id       INT NOT NULL,
  musicrelease_id INT NOT NULL,

  FOREIGN KEY (artist_id) REFERENCES artist (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (musicrelease_id) REFERENCES musicrelease (id),

  UNIQUE (artist_id, musicrelease_id)
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I don't know what is there problem((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a default constructor here.
Since the default constructor is missing here, and only Arg-Constructor is defined.

Add the following snippet in your code to define a default constructor:

```
public Artist(){}
```

This would hopefully solve your problem.

Comment: You're most welcome.
If this was the required solution, do upvote my answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In JPA entity must have default constructor to be able to instantiate an object form the entity, just create an empty constructor, like the following and your problem will be solved.

```
    public Artist(){//do nothing}
```

Comment: you are welcome